# Java - Jersey REST WS JAXB character encoding

Tags: java, web-services, encoding, utf-8, jaxb

I'm getting character encoding artifacts when I send strings with certain characters across the wire. But only if the string is wrapped by a class.

I simplified my code down to focus on the error. Say I have this test class with nothing in it but a String.

```
    @XmlRootElement
public class TestClass implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String testString;

    public String getTestString() {
        return testString;
    }

    public void setTestString(String testString) {
        this.testString = testString;
    }

}
```

And then I call a web service passing this class to it.   The class contains a string with special characters.

```
TestClass t = new TestClass();
    t.setTestString("testfile¢°2");

    WebTarget request = getResource().path("myws").path("stringTester");
    Invocation.Builder builder  = request.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    builder.acceptEncoding("UTF-8");
    Invocation invoker = builder.buildPost(Entity.entity(t, new Variant(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE, (String)null, "UTF-8")));
    Response response = invoker.invoke();
```

Then it gets to my WS

```
@POST
    @Path("/stringTester")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8"})
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8"})
    public Response stringTester(TestClass t) {
        System.out.println("Raw: " + t.getTestString());

        return Response.ok().build();
    }
```

The web service print statement spits out: Raw: testfileÂ¢Â°2

As you can see I've tried to tell it all along the way to stay in UTF-8 though I think that is what java defaults to anyway.

If I take string with garbage characters and do: `System.out.println("UTF-8: " + new String("testfileÂ¢Â°2".getBytes(), "UTF-8"));`

It will correctly print out "UTF-8: testfile¢°2"

If I rejigger the web service to just accept a string instead of a class, do all the same calls the same way and pass testfile¢°2, I get testfile¢°2 on the other side.   So what's going on?

Comment: I switched my service and client to send and receive as APPLICATION_XML and it started working correctly.   I don't have a requirement for the format to make the REST with, so this will work for now though I'm still not sure where the issue is while using JSON.